# Odd/garbled remote output from "git clone" and "git fetch" commands

Tags: git, git-clone, git-fetch

I've been running into some odd server output (line 5 of the block quote, below) when cloning and fetching from a remote Git repository.  I'm wondering if anyone has a thought as to what could be causing it.

```
D:\dev>git clone https://<user>@<repo>
Cloning into '<repo>'...
remote: Counting objects: 345583, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26532/26532), done.
remote: Total 34R558ece3 iv(dinelg taob 3je19ct67s:3) 1, 00re% us(3ed45 358443/25345 55(d83el),ta 2 35418.6591 4)  B
Receiving objects: 100% (345583/345583), 255.40 MiB | 3.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (319673/319673), done.
Checking out files: 100% (16038/16038), done.
```

The server version of Git is 1.8.0.msysgit.0 and the local version of Git is 1.7.11.msysgit.1.  My best guess is this is a potential artifact of the version difference, but numerous other developers on my team use the same version and have not reported such output.

Comment: might be a problem with your terminal configuration

Comment: A terminal configuration problem would be my first suspect, especially given that it looks like the output backspaced on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my local version of Git to 1.8.1.msysgit.1 resolved the issue.  Unfortunately, I was never able to find the underlying problem.